# Selenium fails to locate element even though it's loaded and not in an iframe

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to locate an element in a form, but for some reason Selenium keeps throwing an error saying it can't be found. Here is the simple code that I'm using. Can anyone decipher why this isn't working? It looks like a basic HTML form.

```py
driver = uc.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.stumblechat.com/register')
username = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'user')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems here:

1. You have to wait for element appearance. The best approach is to use `WebDriverWait` `expected_conditions` explicit waits.
2. That element has different locator. You probably looking for element located by this CSS Selector: `input[name='username']`.
   If so, your code can be like following:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url = "https://stumblechat.com/register"

driver.get(url)
username = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='username']")))
```

Comment: Thank you. This works by choosing the CSS_SELECTOR as you suggested.
Do you have any idea why this was required to find that element? For some reason, I was able to find the other elements in the form using By.NAME and By.ID.

Comment: You can locate it using `By.NAME`: `username = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "username")))` but not by ID since that element does not have ID attribute. Why it doesn't have ID attribute? Try asking frontend developers worked on that page :)

Comment: According to the inspector, it appears to have a `name` and `ID` attribute:

`<input type="text" name="user" id="user" placeholder="Username" ...>`


Neither one worked for locating the element, but I can use `name` and `ID` for the other fields in the form.

Comment: In my browser I see this: `<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="on" required="" minlength="3" maxlength="24" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,24}" title="Three or more characters">`

Comment: How peculiar. It looks like the id and name are present on Firefox, but missing on Chrome. I thought that I checked it with Chrome as well and saw them, but perhaps I was mistaken. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Now copied from Firefox `<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="on" required="" minlength="3" maxlength="24" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,24}" title="Three or more characters">` Looks same.